# The archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing

Tags: update

I try to auto upgrade from 3.5.1 to 3.6.0 and get the message 'The archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing"

If I try to Install from URL my message is "Unable to find install package"

If I try to upload the package manually the loader runs for a while and then terminates with no upload nor any message

/logs and /tmp exist and are correctly set in global config

thanks for any insight- Nikos

Comment: Can you verify that your hosting account has enough room for the uploaded file and that the file type (typically zip) is allowed?

Answer (score 2):

For others that may reach here with similar issue for recent Joomla updates (e.g. 3.6.5).

In the case you get this error message, it usually means what it says: That the update package that was transferred to your Joomla instance's tmp folder is indeed corrupted. A corrupted file may occur for various reasons - no need to analyze this here.

If this happens, any new effort to initiate the update procedure through the **Joomla Update Component** will end with the same result - as Joomla will keep finding the corrupted zip file in the **`tmp`** folder and will try to use this for the update.

So the solution here is to connect with **FTP** to your site and go into the **`tmp`** folder of your Joomla and **delete the previous downloaded update package**. This will force the **Joomla Update Component** to fetch and download a new zip archive for updating your Joomla site - hopefully this time the archive will be transferred at full and with no corruption.

Comment: it is worth mentioning that the `temp` folder in this case is the one in `administrator`folder.

Comment: The strange thing is that i am still getting the same error message even when the temp folders are empty. 
and after getting that message, the temp folders are still empty, nothing downloaded there. I have double checked the my temp folders in joomla and in configuration.php. 
I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the "joomla update component" (sorry it may not be the exact wording, I've got a french installation) before updating to 3.6.0 ? I guess you don't do it (?)